# How to find the closest or exact value in a binary search tree in C

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures, struct, binary-search-tree

I have created a C program where a sorted array full of `doubles` is converted into a binary search tree. After the BST is created, I want to find the closest value to my key which is 1.0. As soon as the closest value is reached, my program crashes. However, if my key is an exact value that can be found in the BST, it works perfectly fine and prints the "found" message. Anyone know how I can fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node { 
    double data; 
    struct node* left; 
    struct node* right; 
};

struct node* createnewnode(double data);
struct node* bstcreate(double* arr, int start, int end); 
struct node* search(struct node* root, double key);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    double array[] = {-4.526682861, -3.682840076, -2.953453251,-1.709721126, -0.936102616, 
    0.18335189, 1.038874246, 2.618022636, 3.259094511, 4.198243959};
    
    int index = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])-1;
    //printf("%d\n", index);
    
    struct node *root = bstcreate(array, 0, index);
    search(root, 1.0);
    //search(root, 1.538874246);
    return 0;
}

struct node* bstcreate(double* arr, int start, int end) 
{ 
    if (start > end) 
      return NULL; 
  
    int mid = (start + end)/2; 
    struct node *root = createnewnode(arr[mid]); 

    root->left =  bstcreate(arr, start, mid-1); 
    root->right = bstcreate(arr, mid+1, end); 
  
    return root; 
} 
  
struct node* createnewnode(double data)  
{ 
    struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    node->data = data; 
    node->left = NULL; 
    node->right = NULL; 
  
    return node; 
}

struct node* search(struct node* root, double key) {
    printf("%lf\n",root->data); 
    
    if (root == NULL || root->data == key) {
        printf("Found: %lf\n", root->data);
        return root; 
    }
    
    else if (root->data < key) {
        return search(root->right, key);
    }
    else {
        return search(root->left, key); 
    }
}
```

This is what the output prints before the program crashes:

[image]

Comment: And why does it crash?

Comment: I'm not sure. That's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: Well, think about this. your search only base-cases on `root ==  NULL` or exact match (and the latter isn't going to happen). Before anything else, consider the madness of how the first condition could be true, and what you do immediately *before* that check. I.e. `printf("%lf\n", root->flux);`. Um.... For that matter, even taking that out, consider what's *inside* that check. The same problem, `printf("Found: %lf\n", root->flux);` What do you think *either* of those will do when `root` is `NULL`, which is highly likely (and in fact guaranteed with your sample data)?

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger, to see why it crashes.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I don't see how I could elaborate more. Your search function seeks an exact match, Barring that it will *definitely* recurse to a point where the incoming `root` argument is `NULL`. Given that, consider the very first line of your search function: `printf("%lf\n",root->data);` What do you think that does when `root` is `NULL` ? Ans: It invokes *undefined behavior* and in your case, triggers an access violation trying to dereference a NULL pointer, which terminates your process. Trimming that out, the problem still persists because the exact same problem is *inside* the if-check.

Comment: Okay so the problem is located in the ```if (root == NULL || root->flux == key) {```. Could you give me some hints on what I could do to fix this?

Comment: If `root` is `NULL`, you can _not_ dereference it (e.g. you can _not_ do `root->data` at all). To fix this, in `search`, add this as the _first_ line: `if (root == NULL) return root;` That should fix things. After that, you can remove any `if` clause that has either `root == NULL` or `root != NULL` as after the first [new] line, `root` can't be `NULL` [because we've already checked for it]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct search function:

```
struct node* search(struct node* root, double key) {
     
    if (root == NULL) {
        return root; 
    }
    printf("%lf\n",root->data);
    
    if (root->data == key) {
        printf("Found: %lf\n", root->data);
        return root; 
    }
    else if (root->data < key) {
        return search(root->right, key);
    }
    else {
        return search(root->left, key); 
    }
}
```